# A GreaseMonkey fork/analog that won't collect my data

Tags: gratis, javascript, firefox

I don't like [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)'s [data collection policy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/privacy/). Short of [forking](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/fork) it myself, what are the options for a non-invasive Firefox extension to implement user scripting?

Requirements:

- Source code available
- Gratis
- No data collection from my computers whatsoever

Optional:

- Compatibility with existing GreaseMonkey user scripts

Comment: Scratch that. I have forked and fixed the scripts: https://github.com/Hunter-Github/greasemonkey It works for me, can probably close this question.

Comment: ...or perhaps post a self answer later...

Comment: On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :) Just a pity it won't be long until we no longer can use extensions without Mozilla's own blessings (signing)...

Comment: @Izzy - yep, I do know. However I was torn between that and closing the question as too localized :P

Comment: Have you looked at Scriptish? It's a fork of Greasemonkey as well. Not sure what data is collected there (I wasn't even aware that Greasemonkey collects something).

Comment: Does Greasemonkey still collect data even if you've unchecked 'submit anonymous usage statistics' in its options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a hurry and couldn't bear waiting, so I took the logical step and forked the 'Monkey: https://github.com/Hunter-Github/greasemonkey.

Pros:

- fits my own requirements

Cons:

- took about half an hour, so wasn't exactly gratis
- I didn't put the .xpi package online, thus not accessible on Windows

Comment: "I didn't put the .xpi package online, thus not accessible on Windows" - out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @Mawg - it isn't easy for a layman to verify that the .xpi file corresponds to the source before installation. I may not be trustworthy: )